# Send each line as a single argument in bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

I have a variable in bash, which is something like

```
filenames='file 1
file 2
file 3'
```

I need to send each line in the above variable's content as a single argument to a program. But I can't get bash to that. Here's what I tried:

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' $filenames
['-c', 'file', '1', 'file', '2', 'file', '3']
```

or

```
python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' "$filenames"
['-c', 'file 1\nfile 2\nfile 3']
```

What I'm expecting is something like this

```
['-c', 'file 1', 'file 2', 'file 3']
```

I've tried fiddling with the `IFS` setting too, but couldn't get it right. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-evaluating a command with either `eval` or `sh -c` can lead to weird bugs if you don't get the extra level of quoting just right.   I'd recommend using an array instead, either just by storing the file list as an array to begin with:

```
filearray=("file 1" "file 2" "file 3")
python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' "${filearray[@]}"
```

or by converting it from newline-delimited string to an array:

```
filenames='file 1
file 2
file 3'
oldIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'
filearray=($filenames)
IFS="$oldIFS"
python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' "${filearray[@]}"
```

Comment: +1 This is the perfect solution I've been wanting. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ export filenames="file 1
file 2
file 3"
$ echo "$filenames" | xargs -d\\n python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv'
['-c', 'file 1', 'file 2', 'file 3']
```

Another way using `read` instead of `xargs`:

```
#!/bin/bash
filenames="file 1
file 2
file 3"
cmd="python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv; print sys.stdin.readlines()'"
while read file
do
    args="$args \"$file\""
done < <(echo "$filenames")
echo $cmd $args
echo `echo hi | sh -c "$cmd $args"`
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh 
python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv; print sys.stdin.readlines()' "file 1" "file 2" "file 3"
['-c', 'file 1', 'file 2', 'file 3'] ['hi\n']
```

Comment: whoa! I thought `xargs` runs the command once for each line of input, no?

Comment: Also, I need something else to be going in the `stdin` of the python command, so I don't think this'll do it in its current form.

Comment: Nope, you would need to use the `-n1` option to get that behavior. By default it uses as many arguments as will fit in a line for each invocation (you can redefine "fit" with the `-s` and `-n` options).

Comment: Ah, eval. I had a feeling this'd be the solution. Also, the while loop can be turned to this: `args="$(echo "$filenames" | sed 's/^\|$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' ')"` :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another option,

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS='
'
set -- $filenames
python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv; print sys.stdin.readlines()' "$@"
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

**Edit:** Add code to save old value in `OLDIFS` and restore it afterwards.  `IFS='whatever' set -- $var` on a single line does not work.

Comment: And I was trying `IFS="\n"` and the like, #facepalm. Thanks.

Comment: In bash, `$'\n'` is a literal newline.

Comment: Hm, I remember trying that too. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
while read line ; do
  python -c 'import sys; print sys.argv' $line;
done <(echo $filenames)
```

Comment: Wouldn't any newlines be mutilated because of the echo without quoting?

Answer (score 0):

What about xargs:

```
$ seq 10 | xargs  python -c 'print __import__("sys").argv'
['-c', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
```